# TeXLive portable without tlmgr

Tags: texlive, windows

I have successfully installed a portable TeXLive following the instruction given by [W32TeX](http://w32tex.org/), with a full installation selection on windows 7. The path environment was added with TeXLive bin path, but there is nothing about tlmgr except a manual, i browser stackexchange to find the solutions, google the tlmgr package, and get nothing about the problem.

where and how can i get tlmgr working? thanks

Comment: Do you have `tlmgr.bat` in your `bin/win32` folder?

Comment: there is only a doc "tlmgr.man1.pdf"